# You Have 1 Bitcoin in your account

Tags: fraud

I continue to receive text messages on my mobile advising I've got 1 bitcoin in my account, to go to: http:// (etc) to confirm my account.  However, when I follow the link, there's nothing relevant
Can you help please?

Comment: Do you *expect* to receive text messages like this? If not, then they are probably spam/phishing messages and all the sender wants to do is to get  you to click on a link and infect your phone with a virus. There are unlikely to be any bitcoins for you.

Comment: A bitcoin is currently worth about 6000USD, give or take. I would judge the credibility of such messages accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

It's a scam. Do NOT click. Will be a virus your take your passwords

Answer (score 0):

At this time (2017) no one is going to give you free Bitcoin unless you have bought it from somewhere or something similar.

It is most likely a spam/phishing attempt as @Greg said.

Answer (score 0):

Yup scam. Mine lead back to text.id a domain registered by Christopher Boyd. A security researcher, think someone is trying to frame him. Catch two birds with one stone so to speak. Think the hackers got the info from Gravatar and combined that with some google searching. Either that or a dodgy mining pool where registration is required.